# Logic Pro X: How to avoid loosing comp selections after new vocal take/recording?

Tags: audio-recording, recording, logic-pro, vocals, audio-editor

In Logic Pro X when I record multiple takes and choose my comp selections. After already choosing the selections I want to come back and record another take, but then I lose my previous comp selections. How can I avoid losing my previous comp selections after recording a new vocal take.

As example, when I take 4 takes and have chosen the selections out of those 4 takes:
[image]

When I take the 5th (after already making the comp choices). I loose my previous comp choices and the new take takes over fully.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I just found the asnwer to this question which had been bugging me as well over the past year.   It turns out you can save different comp versions, and these can be selected by clicking on the letter in the upper left corner of the take folder.  When you add takes to a folder with a previous comp, it creates a new version (A,B,C...).    Just click on the letter and go back to you presious comp, and it's all there!.

[image: Comp Drop Down Box]